# How to add EditText input to custom model using data binding adapter?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

This is my data binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("taskMinutes")
public static void taskMinutes(@NonNull TextView view, @NonNull Task task) {
    if (task.getDueDate() == null) {
        view.setText("");
        return;
    }
    view.setText(String.valueOf(DateUtils.getDateMinutes(task.getDueDate())));
}
```

And in `xml`:

```
app:taskMinutes="@{task}"
```

And minutes show in `EditText` normally but didn't add to `task.dueDate`.

**But how can I add adapter for add new input from `EditText` filed to `task.dueDate`?**

Comment: Did you solve it? :)

Comment: @RobertBanyai the solution below might help you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I my case I add an attribute "input" and implement inverseBinding on it

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"input", "inputAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void bindIntegerInText(AppCompatEditText tv, int value, final InverseBindingListener inverseBindingListener)
    {
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        // Set the cursor to the end of the text
        tv.setSelection(tv.getText().length());

        tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                //inverseBindingListener.onChange();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                inverseBindingListener.onChange();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                //inverseBindingListener.onChange();
            }
        });
    }


    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:input", event = "app:inputAttrChanged")
    public static int bindCountryInverseAdapter(AppCompatEditText view) {
        String string = view.getText().toString();
        return string.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_age"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Age"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:input="@={userInfo.age}"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
```

I add a check in my model object to avoid infinite loop between model and view

```
@Bindable
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        Log.d("Age","Age "+age);
        if (this.age != age){
            this.age = age;
            if (this.age != 0)
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.age);
        }
    }
```

**There is another simple way of doing this::**

# Write a class for conversion and add this two methods

```
    public class Conversion {

    @InverseMethod("toInt")
    public static String toString(int age) {
        return age == 0 ? null : String.valueOf(age);
    }

    public static int toInt(String string) {
        return string.isEmpty() ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(string);
    }
}
```

`@InverseMethod("toInt")` means, `toInt()` method will be called for data inversion.

# In XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_age"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Age"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="@={Conversion.toString(userInfo.age)}"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_password"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />
```

# Import the Conversion class in the layout file

```
<import type="bytes.wit.databinding.Conversion"/>
```

Comment: The second part is by far the cleanest implementation I seen that works all around. I would change the toString() method to return "0" if age is 0 or else if it is set age in code to 0, the edit text will stay blank.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should find this article useful for conversions with EditText

https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873

You can do 2-way conversion functions in an easier way than InverseBindingAdapers.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on two-way data binding. You have to define an [InversBindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter.html).